# Firefox addon to sniff XHR headers without crashing into CSP?

Tags: ajax, redirect, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, request-headers

I wrote an addon for Firefox trying to eavesdrop on the headers of certain XHR calls of a site not my own. I tried to redirect them to a server running at localhost but ran into Content Security Policy. It was denied.

So what's the best way to have those headers sent to localhost? Is there a nice way? I know I can browser log them and pick them up from there, but that's manual and tedious.

I could make certain XHR calls from a content script which return the data in the headers, but again that's somewhat awkward. The ideal way is to intercept the calls with the desired headers.